# What is purpose of the following Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I have a C code which translates to the following assembly,

```
pop rax
mov rax, [rax]
push rax
```

My understanding of the above instruction set is:
Update the value of rax to the value at the address it contains.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Also push it back onto the stack. Obviously the address used isn't the original value of `rax`, it's popped from the stack. So it's more like "replace the value at the top of the stack with the value it points to, and set rax to the same value too"

Comment: You could simplify this code to `pop rax; push [rax]` if it doesn't matter what value `rax` has in the end.

Comment: @fuz In this case it does matter(?) i think, am later moving value in rdi to [rax] and then pushing rdi.

Comment: @sweetsecret Fair enough then.

Comment: You got a C compiler to emit that asm, really?  What compiler, compiling what source?  I don't think I've ever seen a mainstream C compiler (gcc/clang/MSVC/ICC) emit `pop` to reload data from the stack except as part of restoring registers before a `ret`.  And definitely not `push`ing it again afterwards.  If a compiler couldn't keep a linked-list pointer in registers, you'd expect something like `mov rax, [rbp-8]` / `mov rax, [rax]` / `mov [rbp-8], rax` ; addressing locals relative to RBP or RSP is normal.  Or is this a toy compiler like in [this Q&A](//stackoverflow.com/q/62542955)?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, it is a toy compiler. It takes C-like code and emits assembly.

Comment: C can have multiple local variables; accessing them via `pop` won't scale past 1, so I'd recommend not doing that.  You could special case the variable that happens to be at the lowest address in the stack frame, but that seems like unnecessary complication for a toy compiler.  The Q&A I linked is for a compiler for stack-machine bytecode or something, not a C-like language.

Comment: @PeterCordes It does work pretty well for temporary results in expressions though.